# Stored Procedure doesn't return affected rows after exception handling

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have added exception handling in my stored procedure as below.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[BUDGETUPDATE] 
 @DistrictID        int
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON ;

 BEGIN TRY
         BEGIN TRAN
                    UPDATE bud
                    SET bud.BudgetStateID    = @BudgetStateID
                    FROM [dbo].[BudgetOffice] bud
                        INNER JOIN [dbo].[vw_Office] vw
                            ON (vw.OfficeID   = bud.OfficeID)
                        WHERE   vw.DistrictID = @DistrictID
         IF @@ERROR = 0
      BEGIN   
          COMMIT TRAN;
          SELECT @@ROWCOUNT AS AffectedRow;
      END
 END TRY
 BEGIN CATCH
           SELECT @@ERROR AS ERROR
 ROLLBACK TRAN;
 END CATCH

 SET NOCOUNT OFF ;

 END
```

I need to return the number of affected rows using `@@ROWCOUNT`. But this `stored procedure` always returns rowcount as 0. Any reason for this. Do I need to write the `@@rowcount` statement right after `update`?

Comment: I think you need to select `@@rowcount` after the `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to select `@@ROWCOUNT` after your `UPDATE` statement. As per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx):

> Statements such as USE, SET , DEALLOCATE CURSOR, CLOSE CURSOR,
>   BEGIN TRANSACTION or COMMIT TRANSACTION reset the ROWCOUNT value to 0.

Since your `@@ROWCOUNT` is after the `COMMIT TRAN`, `@@ROWCOUNT` returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store result of global variables in local variable because it will change after next instruction like:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[BUDGETUPDATE] 
 @DistrictID        int
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON ;
 DECLARE @rowcount INT, @error INT;

 BEGIN TRY
         BEGIN TRAN
                    UPDATE bud
                    SET bud.BudgetStateID = @BudgetStateID
                    FROM [dbo].[BudgetOffice] bud
                    JOIN [dbo].[vw_Office] vw
                      ON vw.OfficeID   = bud.OfficeID
                    WHERE vw.DistrictID = @DistrictID;

      SELECT @error = @@ERROR, @rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT;

      IF @error = 0
      BEGIN   
          COMMIT TRAN;
          SELECT @rowcount AS AffectedRow;
      END

 END TRY
 BEGIN CATCH
     SELECT @@ERROR AS ERROR
     ROLLBACK TRAN;
 END CATCH
 END
```

Or even better resign for using `@@ERROR` in `TRY CATCH` block:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[BUDGETUPDATE] 
 @DistrictID        int
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON ;

 BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN
           UPDATE bud
           SET bud.BudgetStateID = @BudgetStateID
           FROM [dbo].[BudgetOffice] bud
           JOIN [dbo].[vw_Office] vw
             ON vw.OfficeID   = bud.OfficeID
           WHERE vw.DistrictID = @DistrictID;

           SELECT @@ROWCOUNT AS AffectedRow;

    COMMIT TRAN; 
 END TRY
 BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ERROR
    ROLLBACK TRAN;
 END CATCH
 END
```

And where is `@BudgetStateID` defined?

Comment: I took the part of code for demonstration. Forget to add @budgetstatid in input parameters list :)

Comment: Do we need to add no count on here? If we add will I get no of rows affected count?

Comment: @Vicky `SET COUNT ON` is optional. Number of affected rows message  is most of the cases noise